What was the first science fiction story set in the future?
One could argue that science fiction is very old indeed, but the early
fantasy/science fiction (and "science fiction" is used loosely although maybe the ancient Greeks had stories involving automata?) tends to be set in a distant land or even another planet, not in the future.
Rip van Winkle is set in Rip's future but the narrator's present and it is not science fiction at all, but fantasy.
The motivation for the question is discovering when the idea that the people of the future would be more advanced than those of the writer's time. There was certainly a period in history where this would have been a new kind of idea -- prior to the 1600s, people believed that it was the ancient Greeks and Romans who knew things that people of the, say, 1500s did not know and needed to rediscover. Moreover, I do not think most people experienced any kind of significant technological progress during their lifetimes until maybe the late 1700s -- by the late 1700s, an educated person would have seen the advances especially in chemistry and astronomy and be able to extrapolate.
I am aware of books written in the 1800s of course, maybe the best known being Looking Backward which imagined a better future and certainly most people alive when this novel was published in 1888 would have been aware of many technological advances.
Could in fact Bellamy's novel be the first that imagined a very changed and more advanced future which I think qualifies it as a true science fiction novel? I suspect that others preceded Bellamy, since quite a few inventions that affected multiple people arose before 1888.
Note: As I thought, based on comments/answers it was relatively late that writers thought of the future as being advanced technologically and in the 1700s, it would have been a very visionary writer indeed to extrapolate the advances of that century (primarily in math but very limited in applied inventions) to a future of, say, instantaneous communications. I think it was the invention of the telegraph and then the laying of the Transatlantic Cable that must have really stimulated 19th century writers into seeing a trend. I was just reading about the idea that a message that would have taken weeks to cross the ocean taking only ten minutes. The widespread use of steam must also have impressed people. Maybe some other advances, like Babbage's were not well-known or understood by most. The advent of electric lighting and motors might have convinced people that progress was inevitable.

@fez: it's different because a story like Rip van Winkle did not have the old man impressed by technological improvements. Science definitely progressed a lot while Rip slept, but he would not have been exposed to it. And it was not even hinted at in Irving's story.

@releseabe - you're looking for the first story set in the future, the dupe is also looking for the first story set in the future. An answer to this question would be an answer to that question, therefore dupe

@fez: I  am looking for the first SCIENCE FICTION story set in the future. I explained this. If the future is reached by magic and the future looks the same, then it is not scfi.

@releseabe - the dupe is also looking for science fiction stories set in the future. The science fiction genre tag, and  "lots of science fiction stories today are set in the future [...] What was the first story to do this?" say it pretty explicitly.

Prior to the 1600s, people believed that it was the ancient Greeks and Romans who knew things. Not necessarily. Prior to the 1800's, exotic societies are found in distant lands, not in the distant future. Most Renaissance utopias were more advanced socially than their European visitors and our Ancients, although typically not technologically. Swift's utopias (1726) have advanced technology w/resp to Gulliver's home country.

@FrançoisJurain: Yes, people have imagined distant lands different/more advanced than their native countries. But as I have explained, I am interested in when people started to believe something that we all take for granted today: That with the passage of time, progress (or at least change) is likely to occur. I believe, perhaps wrongly, that for may centuries people did not even think much of the coming centuries. I would be  quite surprised if someone writing in 1000 AD said, "I wonder what people living in 2000 AD will be like."

Well, as early as ~100 AD, you could read "And I John saw the holy city coming down from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. And I heard a great voice out of heaven saying, Behold, the tabernacle of God with men, and he will dwell with them, and they shall be his people". Some readers, although not all, took this to mean the fun would start ~1000yrs thence.

Ah, about futuristic technology! Sorry, misread theology, my bad. Still, good sci-fi, well written, good read.

David W's answer has an example from the year 1851.
I have an example a few years earlier.  Edgar Allen Poe's "Mellonta Tauta" (1849) set in the year 2848, in which much scientific progress has been made.
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2150/2150-h/2150-h.htm#chap4.12

I am not sure I read Poe's elaborate language rightly, but was his imagination so limited that all he could come up with for improved transportation 1000 years hence was a balloon made of silk?? Why were people not imagining rocket-propelled vehicles since rockets (used in warfare but I think someone experimented, at least in legend, with attaching them to a chair) were hardly new in 1849.

There's Memoirs Of The Year Two Thousand Five Hundred (1772):

A science fiction novel written by Louis-Sebastien Mercier in 1772. The book is set in the year 2500 and depicts a utopian society.—Amazon

Read a full English translation online.

Bleiler: "The author’s interest is almost wholly in society, and there is very little about scientific or technological progress, which Mercier did not rate highly."

@DavidW: The important idea is that way back in 1772, a time I guess when people were thinking about societal change, the author foresaw progress. One could easily argue that the science in the book (without having read it) is sociology/social science. This may be the earliest.

A bit of browsing through Bleiler (Science-Fiction: The Early Years) turns up entry 659, from 1851:

ELLIS, JANE A.
Student at Oberlin College.
659 A VISION OF OUR COUNTRY IN THE YEAR NINETEEN HUNDRED.  The Western Literary Magazine and Journal of Education, Science, Arts, and Morals.  Published by the Editor, George Brewster, Columbus, Ohio, 1851.  The story is published as by J.A.E.
An admirable future as seen by a student at Oberlin College. * Short sketch. * At sunset, the narrator, reclining in her easy chair, considering the "remarkable improvements and discoveries of the last century," finds that she is in the year 1900. * The United States has expanded to take in the whole western hemisphere, and the country is enormously developed. New York has a population of 1,484,418. There is no more poverty or want. Electricity is the chief power source, and many great discoveries have been made. Water serves as fuel. Aerial locomotion is easy and pleasant, and railroads are very efficient. Crime has almost disappeared, and Europe has shaken off the shackles of despotism. * Visiting the college plant of Oberlin, the narrator finds everything changed, with elegant stone edifices replacing the rather ramshackle wooden erections of the past. Only the old chapel remains, and as its bell tolls, the narrator awakes. * A pleasant early utopian sketch.


Aside:  The discussion for New Atlantis (1626) notes that it includes the concept of progress, but it isn't really shown or discussed in any depth.
